# Eclipse rename/refactoring override

Tags: eclipse, refactoring, overriding, rename

I am new to eclipse plug-in development. I want to customize the renaming of a project. I need to validate the new name. So how can I override eclipse's rename/refactoring method?

I saw something related to RenameParticipant, but didn't understand clearly. It would be great if someone could explain me steps to override the renaming functionality.

Many Thanks,
Ann

Answer (score 15):

The rename refactoring has several processors that subclass [`org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.participants.RenameProcessor`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/eclipse.org/3.6.1/org.eclipse.ltk.core/refactoring/3.5.100/org/eclipse/ltk/core/refactoring/participants/RenameProcessor.java#RenameProcessor) and are responsible for renaming different elements. For example, there is a processor for renaming Java projects [`org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.refactoring.rename.RenameJavaProjectProcessor`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/eclipse.org/3.6.1/org.eclipse.jdt/ui/3.6.1/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/corext/refactoring/rename/RenameJavaProjectProcessor.java#RenameJavaProjectProcessor). A refactoring participant can participate in the condition checking and change creation of a refactoring processor. For example, to check some conditions during a rename refactoring, you should subclass [`org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.participants.RenameParticipant`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/eclipse.org/3.6.1/org.eclipse.ltk.core/refactoring/3.5.100/org/eclipse/ltk/core/refactoring/participants/RenameParticipant.java#RenameParticipant), override the method [`org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.participants.RefactoringParticipant.checkConditions(IProgressMonitor, CheckConditionsContext)`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/eclipse.org/3.6.1/org.eclipse.ltk.core/refactoring/3.5.100/org/eclipse/ltk/core/refactoring/participants/RefactoringParticipant.java#RefactoringParticipant.checkConditions%28org.eclipse.core.runtime.IProgressMonitor,org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.participants.CheckConditionsContext%29) and register the participant via the extension point `org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.renameParticipants`. The participant [`org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.refactoring.nls.NLSAccessorFieldRenameParticipant`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/eclipse.org/3.6.1/org.eclipse.jdt/ui/3.6.1/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/corext/refactoring/nls/NLSAccessorFieldRenameParticipant.java#NLSAccessorFieldRenameParticipant) gives you a good example of how to participate in a rename refactoring.

When you declare your extension of the `org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.renameParticipants` extension point, you should specify the element you'd like your participant to get notified about. For example, see how the following use of the `org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.renameParticipants` extension point in [`org.eclipse.jdt.ui/plugin.xml`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/eclipse.org/3.6.1/org.eclipse.jdt/ui/3.6.1/plugin.xml/?v=source) involves the participant in renaming fields.

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.renameParticipants">
  <renameParticipant class="org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.refactoring.nls.NLSAccessorFieldRenameParticipant" id="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.NLSFieldRenameParticipant" name="%Refactoring.NLSFieldRenameParticipant">
    <enablement>
      <with variable="affectedNatures">
        <iterate operator="or">
          <equals value="org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature"/>
        </iterate>
      </with>
      <with variable="element">
        <instanceof value="org.eclipse.jdt.core.IField"/>
      </with>
    </enablement>
  </renameParticipant>
</extension>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. I subclassed RenameParticipant. Overrid method checkConditions. And registered the participant via extension point. Now it does validation for everything(ie for projects, files etc). I want validation only for project name. I didnt understand where I can place the RenameJavaProjectProcessor. Thanks,

Comment: `RenameJavaProjectProcessor` is in JDT and you don't have to worry about it. You just need to specify the element your participant works on when you declare your extension point in `plugin.xml`. See my updated answer on how to specify the element on which your participant operates.

Comment: @reprogrammer I am stuck with similar problem now. I followed your steps and I get to update each time refactor happens, but I have my own custom editor and in this editor the refactor option is disabled and hence I am unable to perform refactor in this editor.