# Override rename action in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am new to eclipse plugin development. I am in the need of overriding the rename dialog for the files in a specific custom project. Say I am having a file "sample.abcd" in the custom project that has its own perspectives, natures and builders. So whenever i try to rename this file, I am getting a rename dialog with the file extension. I want to override this dialog displaying only the file name just like a java project rename action does. Can you point me to any resource, how to do it ? Thanks [image: Current rename action]

Comment: Do you really need to change/extend the Eclipse workbench, or do you probably want to use the jdt(?)-rename feature from within a custom dialog? I guess, you may trigger the command "by hand" from your own dialog.

Comment: I want the users not to view the respective extension while renaming. Just to edit its name. Just like we do for java file in java project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to implement a [rename refactoring participant](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_ltk_core_refactoring_renameParticipants.html?cp=2_1_1_103). Its "enablement" condition specifies under which circumstances it shall be involved (you would have to check for your specific file extension).

A longer explanation can also be found in [Eclipse rename/refactoring override](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6618495/eclipse-rename-refactoring-override).