# Hide the file extension in Rename Resource dialog of eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, resources, swt, rename

I have a requirement to hide the file extension in `Rename Resource` dialog of `eclipse`, like `fileName.abc`, and just show the file name `fileName` without the extension. Is there any way to implement that?

Comment: If you have access to the variable, take a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/941272/how-do-i-trim-a-file-extension-from-a-string-in-java

Comment: Thanks for your replying, but that's not what I mean, I am developping the eclipse plugin. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13173188/override-rename-action-in-eclipse, is similar to mine, I want to show the "sample" but not "sample.abcd". It seems that I should override some jdt api like Rename action to achieve it, do you have any idea?

Comment: JDT does this by using a different refactoring wizard. I don't see a way to alter the normal `Rename Resource` refactoring wizard (but the refactoring code is very complex and I may have missed something).