# Eclipse Extending RenameParticipant

Tags: eclipse-plugin

In order to create a participant on the renaming process, acording to this:

[Eclipse rename/refactoring override](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6618495/eclipse-rename-refactoring-override?answertab=active#tab-top)

it is enough to extend the class and add the extension point in plugin.xml to make it work.

Somehow i cannot make it work, Eclipse just ignores my custom participant.

this is the extension point declared in my plugin.xml:

```
   <extension point="org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.renameParticipants">
      <renameParticipant 
        class="MyCustomRenameParticipant" 
        name="MyCustomRenameParticipant" 
        id="MyCustomRenameParticipant">
        <enablement>
          <with variable="affectedNatures">
            <iterate operator="or">
              <equals value="org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature"/>
            </iterate>
          </with>
          <with variable="element">
             <or>
               <instanceof value="org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource"/>
               <instanceof value="org.eclipse.jdt.core.IJavaElement"/>
             </or>
          </with>
        </enablement>
      </renameParticipant>
    </extension>
```

Any thoughts on what is wrong there?

Right now i want to catch any rename action, of any sort, and my code it's not executed on any case that i have tried

Comment: Make sure the relevant Eclipse Application launch configuration has "Clear the configuration area before launching" checked on its Configuration tab.  If it wasn't, do so and then retry.

Comment: Thanks for your reply nitind, sadly it didn't change anything :/

Comment: The `class` argument probably needs the full class name including the package

Comment: Yes, you _have_ to put it in a package.

Comment: Thanks to both of you, unfortunately the name i'm giving there is a fake, its just to obscure the name of the project. Anyway i already solved it.